# k-file-error when kendo upload is successfull

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, ecmascript-6

I manage to upload files with Kendo and AngularJS, but my files remain red and have a k-file-error class, the files are uploaded and I can have them on the back. Why is there an error ? Could you please help me ?

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div>
            <h4>Upload files</h4>
            <div class="dropZoneElement">Drag and drop file here</div>
            <input name="files"
              ng-model="vm.files"
              type="file"
              kendo-upload
              k-async="{ saveUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/upload/', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: true, withCredentials: false }"
              k-select="onSelect"
              k-upload="onUpload"
              k-progress="onProgress"
              k-success="onSuccess"
              options="vm.options"
              />
        </div>
        <button ng-click="vm.test()">Test</button>
    </div>

class DocumentController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor($scope, authTokenService) {
    this.name = 'document';
    $scope.onSelect = e => {
      // console.log(e.files);
    };
    $scope.onUpload = e => {
      const token = authTokenService.getToken();
      // Check if the token is expire
      if (token && authTokenService.isExpired(token)) {
        authTokenService.setToken();
      }
      const xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;
      if (xhr) {
        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
          if (xhr.readyState === 1) {
            // Add the token to the header
            if (token) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
    $scope.onSuccess = e => {
      console.log(e);
    };
    $scope.onProgress = e => {
      // console.log(e);
    };
    this.options = {
      dropZone: '.dropZoneElement'
    };
  }
}

export default DocumentController;
```

Comment: What is your server action(http://localhost:5000/api/upload) returning?  All the upload demos have this: "// Return an empty string to signify success".

Answer (score 0):

You should return a valid JSON result from your server response. Even `return json(true)` should work.